# HttpModule to catch all extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created HttpModule in ASP.NET, and configured it successfully.
My problem is, the module is called only when I give the URL extension (i.e. aspx), if i dont put any extension, the module won't be called.

How can I solve this?

thanks

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the request is not being handled by ASP.Net - IIS 6 and below only invokes ASP.Net when it encounters a filename that it associates with ASP.Net, such as an .aspx or .axd file extension.

This is similar to the problem faced when attempting to deploy MVC applications to IIS 6 or below (IIS fails to route the requests to ASP.Net), and the solutons are also similar - you can either individually map every extension you wish to see handled to `aspnet_isapi.dll` the ASP.Net handler (which still won't work for URLs that don't have extensions), or you need to use a wildcard mapping to tell IIS to direct **all** requests to ASP.Net - note that this will include images and other static files which might get handled less efficiently than normal.

The article [Deploying ASP.NET MVC to IIS 6](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) discusses the solutions for deploying MVC applications to IIS 6 - this discusses potential solutions with greater detail than I have space for here.